# There are two spinners with 5 spaces numbered 0 to 4.

Tags: probability

There are two spinners with 5 spaces numbered 0 to 4. You spin them both and get paid the higher of the two spins. What's the expected value of your earnings.

I was thinking 
The number of ways to roll a number $x$ would be $2(x−1)+1$.

and taking the expected value with summation ( $x=0$ to $4$). But I got 2 from this, however, shouldn't the expected value of 2 spinners be higher than 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rather easy to list all the possibilites in this case, since there are only $25$ of them. The probabilities of the outcome (the maximum of the two) are the following:

- $P(0) = \frac{1}{25}$
- $P(1) = \frac{3}{25}$
- $P(2) = \frac{5}{25}$
- $P(3) = \frac{7}{25}$
- $P(4) = \frac{9}{25}$

And therefore the expected value is 
$$1 \cdot  \frac{3}{25} +
2 \cdot \frac{5}{25} + 
3 \cdot \frac{7}{25} +
4 \cdot \frac{9}{25} = \frac{14}{5} =2.8
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Say, two i.i.d. uniform random variables $X,Y$ defined over $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ are drawn and your income is $M=\max\{X,Y\}$. So what are$$\Pr\{M<m\}$$ and $$E\{M\}$$?

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways to have greatest be $k$ or less is $(k+1)^2$. Therefore, the number of ways to have the greatest be exactly $k$ is $(k+1)^2-k^2=2k+1$. Thus, the expected value is
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sum\limits_{k=0}^nk(2k+1)}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^n(2k+1)}
&=\frac{\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\left[4\binom{k}{2}+3\binom{k}{1}\right]}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\left[2\binom{k}{1}+\binom{k}{0}\right]}\\
&=\frac{4\binom{n+1}{3}+3\binom{n+1}{2}}{2\binom{n+1}{2}+\binom{n+1}{1}}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{n(4n+5)}{6(n+1)}
\end{align}
$$
For $n=4$, we get
$$
\frac{84}{30}=\frac{14}5
$$